# How to stop the alarm when the notification bar is dragged?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I designed an alarm service application. In that application, whenever an alarm starts, it will show in the notification bar. The problem is that I want to stop the alarm as well as the notification, whenever I drag the notification bar.

Here's my code:

```
if(pYear==pYear2 && pMonth==pMonth2 && pDay==pDay2 && pHour==pHour2 && pMin==pMin2 && pSec==psec2)
{

 Context context = getApplicationContext();

 Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);

 PendingIntent intent1 =PendingIntent.getActivity(MyAlarmService.this, 0, notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 
 Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Alert, Click Me!",System.currentTimeMillis());

 notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Alaram", "Get back to Application on clicking me", intent1);

 mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);

 AudioManager am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);

try
{
    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), ringtoneUri);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //exception caught in the end zone
}
```

Comment: check this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

Comment: thnq but it was not related to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to play notification sounds you should use 
notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;